# Any java XML tree libraries where all value types are immutable

Tags: java, xml

Im just wondering if there are any good complete ones out there. By immutable i mean ones that are always immutable. If the library includes freeze() or equivalent methods to make some value instance immutable then plz make note of this in your reply. I am mostly intersted in libraries that return new copies when a change is made to said node.

To start off with i am going to list a few common libraries which are NOT immutable.

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

> removeAttributeNS(java.lang.String namespaceURI, java.lang.String
>   localName) 
>             Removes an attribute by local name and namespace URI.  void setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value) 
>             Adds a new attribute.

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Comment.html

> Comment  setText(java.lang.String text) 
>             This will set the value of the Comment.

*Note* all important classes include setters.

http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/index.html?nu/xom/Attribute.html

> setType(Attribute.Type type)
>
> ```
>        Sets the type of this attribute to one of the ten DTD types or Type.UNDECLARED.  void  setValue(String value) 
>
>        Sets the attribute's value to the specified string, replacing any previous value.
> ```

If you have any comments about immutability killing performance, then free to make them but provide some real tasty info rather than a boring opinion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you want this for? Maybe you could read the relevant XML data into some other type of immutable data structure, do your stuff, convert it back to XML and write it out. I guess that's exactly what the library is supposed to take care of for you, but depending on what you're trying to do maybe it's an option?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're just using the wrong language—Scala and Clojure both have XML libraries with immutable nodes. I don't think the concept of immutable data structures is popular enough in the Java community for someone to develop a whole production-ready XML library based on it.

If you're willing to pull in the whole Scala library jar then maybe you could write some nice Java wrappers around the [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/) library and use that. It *is* possible to call Scala libraries from Java code, but in my experience it's kind of a pain.

***Update:***

Since you don't seem to be getting any other hits, this might be your most viable option. I was looking into it earlier, and it would be a *horrible pain* to write a wrapper for Anti-XML in Java—but it wouldn't be that bad to write a Java-friendly interface in Scala and then access that interface from Java. Anti-XML's [Zippers](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html) seem to be just what you need for updating immutable XML trees by making copies. The of support for deep zippers seems like a bit of an inconvenience, but it probably isn't a deal-breaker.

Comment: It's 2016 and the situation is unchanged, even though functional programming has become popular with java 8.